# Is there a way to block 100s of emails monthly asking $67-120. "Transfer" fee; & is it poss.. 2collect mining frm all apps/sites prior usd w/ my email

Tags: wallet, security, blockchain.info

Question one; I get literally hundreds of emails about I need to pull my crypto in 24 hours then they take u to the same green dominated site with kaylee in comments stating new then add up a bunch more u recieved daily for a month or so and want money. now theyve gotten clever and it's from a sender must pay for "transfer" or going back to sender purple being the new dominating color scheme. HOW DO I GET RID OF THEM . UHG. I didn't know but spent hours trying to figure how to get paid w/out giving them money. Thank goodness I did not but the loss of time thing is really not cool.
Second I have installed several mining apps & thenphone broke..Several! I lost 2 number has changed 2 or 3 x . I am not experienced just starting crypto but I've been mining it for a couple years here and there.Is there someway to go collect all the little stuff in these sites or apps ........
Also is it right to **buy crypto** through a mining app and then be told I cannot withdraw till I reach the minimum mining withdraw and then I threatened legal and they sent a metamask link w/instructions that say how to connect wallet but then I need a dollar in it in "tokens" & they are only giving me 1 (one)( they aren't *GIVING* me anything I paid for the majority.) so they say type 1. My account says **btm 2.000020298** & that I have 11 hours to do so but when trying to do that they want 20 bucks I can't even put $1. in the account. & its only a flash of instructions once every couple days . I downloaded the instructions but it wont open . Can someone help please.
.